# Regular Expression regexp - Character Range, word boundary, assertions

Tags: regex, cpu-word, expression, boundary

A very quick question.

Here is the expression:

```
/[a-zA-Z]{1,}/
```

I want this expression to match only those letters. But it also seems to match "=" (equals sign). Am I doing something wrong?

For example:

```
/\B#{1}(__){1}(F|OB){1}_{1}([a-zA-Z]{1,})={1}\B/
```

This should match: `#__OB_someText=`
The problem is it also matches this: `#__OB_someText==` or this `#__OB_someText====2`
The equal sign should appear only once.

I probably don't understand much about these assertions: `\b \B`.

Comment: Your regex is ok - what are you running it in?

Comment: hmmm.. M42 is correct of course. Your regex will return the correct matched part if you (captured it) but you actually want it to _fail_ if = is not followed by a word boundary...

Comment: ...or did you intend \b, word boundary, at start and end?

Comment: Yeah, kinda. Anyway it's a bad question. I'll work by it by my self.

Comment: It is a bad question because I'm not telling the whole picture. Forget about it. I just wanted to use that equal sign for something. It should tell something if it is there.

Answer (score 1):

`\B` stands for NON word boundary, there is no non-word-boundary between `=` and `=`

use this regex instead:

```
/\B#(__)(F|OB)_([a-zA-Z]+)=[^=]/
```

`{1}` can be omitted

`{1,}` is the same as `+`

`[^=]` means any character that is not `=`

Comment: {1} can be omitted - yes.
{1,} is the same as + - I like this one {1,} better.
[^=] means any character that is not = - thank you ^^